# data from socket io doesn't show all in view

Tags: angular, nativescript

I get data from socket io this JSON every 10 sec..

```
data { "nr": "1" }
data { "nr": "2" }
.
.
.
.
data { "nr": "5555" }
```

I have this function in ts:

```
....
mydata:any;

constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
  super()
}

....
socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
  this.zone.run(()=> {
    console.log('data', data);
    this.mydata= data;
  }); 
});
```

in html Nativescript:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label text={{mydata}}></Label><br/>
</StackLayout>
```

Now, the problem is in view, I want to print in view all data, 1, 2, 3, 4,..., 5555

not only end of point 5555

Any idea please how to print all data?

Comment: Since you have object and you want to iterate over them, you need to create and Array with all the info and push into that on every event. So `mydata: Array<any>; ` and instead of this.mydata= data; do `this.mydata.push(data);` and in HTML `<Label *ngFor="let label of mydata; let i = index" text={{label }}></Label>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert `mydata` into an array.

**HTML**

```
<StackLayout >
        <!-- json pipe just neatly outputs the data -->
        <Label text={{ mydata | json }}></Label>
       <!-- Or to list items one by one --->
       <Label *ngFor="let label of mydata; let i = index" text={{ label.nr }}> 
       </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**TS**
    ....

```
mydata:any = [];

constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
    super()
}

    ....
    socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
        this.zone.run(()=> {
           console.log('data', data);
           this.mydata.push(data);
        }); 
    });
```

**Note:** `<br>` tag is invalid in {N} environment